# How to use latexindent in TeXStudio on Windows?

Tags: miktex, texstudio, latexindent

I am using TeXStudio with MiKTeX on my Windows 10 computer. I would like TeXStudio to automatically handle the code's indentation in my tex-files, so I enabled *Indentation mode* under the *Editor* settings. However, that is not sufficient, since the indentation is not always correct. After some research on the internet, I discovered that there is a useful script *latexindent* which ships with MiKTeX.

How am I supposed to use *latexindent*? Is it 'activated' automatically while TeXing or is there some key combination to run the script? I am a bit confused for the moment and also surprised that I cannot find any documentation about this topic.

Comment: Could you be more specific about "handling" indentation? Because as far as I know, indentation mode in TXS is only regarding code (i.e. Copy and paste, and automatic indentation when hitting enter on an indented line) so maybe its unrelated.

Comment: `latexindent` is not magical. It is a short script that you need to call. just like you do with BibTeX, or biber, or makeindex. Have a look at the documentation to find more information.

Comment: Maybe the video ["latexindent.pl demonstration (using arara)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_AMmNVg5WM) helps.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos: I am talking about the code in my tex-files. "handling" indentation is what you see in the video that gernot refers to: the correct indentation is automatically applied while the user types.

Comment: @Johannes_B: yes, but how do I "call" the script? I have read the documentation several times, but I still don't get it...

Comment: You need to open a command line and compile by hand* or use the awesome tool called `arara`. Configuring your editor to use `arara` is easy.

Comment: Try `"C:/Users/MyComputer/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/latexindent/latexindent.exe" -w  %.tex`

Comment: The `%` just refers to the basename, `i.e.` the file name without the file extension. But the extension is needed for the script. You can add it as a self answer, you did most of the job. ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following works for me without any other necessities, such as `arara`.

1. Install *latexindent* via MiKTeX Console > Packages.
2. Download [*latexindent* on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent) (zip-file).
3. Navigate to `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexindent` and replace the files in there with the files from the downloaded zip-file in step 2.
4. Create a new User Command in TeXStudio > Options > Build: `"C:/Programs Files/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/latexindent/latexindent.exe" -w -s %.tex`

[image: User Command]

Calling this new command via Tools > User, should run *latexindent* and indent your file! You can even assign a shortcut to the User Command at TeXStudio > Options > Shortcuts to make things quicker.

**Note**: As Johannes_B pointed out in the comments above (thanks!) and as mentioned in [TeXStudio's manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02), the `%` just refers to the basename, i.e. the file name without the file extension. But the extension is needed for the script. If you also want to use *latexindent* for other extensions, you can replace `%.tex` by `?c:me"`, which is equivalent to the current document's filename with the extension attached. To conclude, if the backup files generated by `-w` annoy you, you can use `-s -o ?c:me" ?c:me"` instead; this will directly override your `tex`-file without backups.

Comment: If MikTeX installs the script, you don't need to download from CTAN.

Comment: @Johannes_B: In my fresh installation, MiKTeX 2.9 only included `defaultSettings.yaml`, `indent.yaml` and `latexindent.pl`. Unless one installs Perl and uses the `pl` file instead of an `exe`, my solution therefore doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, MikTeX doesn t include the exe? That is bad. :-(

Comment: @Johannes_B: Indeed, unless I have missed something. :-)

Comment: I do have a latexindent.exe in my miktex/bin folder. But it is not the standalone executable, it is a small wrapper for `perl latexindent.pl`, so it needs an external perl.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know of this -- I'll contact the MikTeX maintainer and ask them to fix this.

Comment: for reference, I contacted the maintainer today -- not sure what the turn around time is. (I'm working on latexindent v3.0 currently)

Comment: +1 your workaround for back up files is valid, but I need to emphasize that I don't recommend it. There are ways to limit the number of backups; for example, you can instruct latexindent to only create one back up using onlyOneBackUp, see https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-default-user-local.html

Comment: @cmhughes did the maintainer every get back to you? I noticed that the MikTeX version still does not include the .exe file.

Comment: I've tried several times to influence change with miktex, but no success. I've even got a dedicated tag https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/issues?q=is%3Aissue+label%3AMikTeX+is%3Aclosed