# TeXStudio code indent respective blocks

Tags: indentation, texstudio

I am using TeXStudio, and I got some LaTeX code from a friend that is all aligned vertically instead of being indented at respective blocks. Is there a command to highlight all of them and indent the code based on the environment?

Comment: Try the script [`latexindent`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent).

Comment: You could even try making a user command for `latexindent`: see step 4 and screenshot in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334511/