# How to use latexindent on Windows?

Tags: miktex, windows, latexindent

I want to use *latexindent* on my file. When I run the code

```
latexindent.exe myfile.tex
```

I get the following error.

```
Can't locate LatexIndent/Document.pm in @INC (you may need to install the LatexIndent::Document module) (@INC contains: /c/Users/adali/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at C:\Users\adali\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts/latexindent\latexindent.pl line 27.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\adali\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts/latexindent\latexindent.pl line 27.
```

(By the way `latexindent.pl myfile.tex` also gives the same error. And I checked my local files and there is a file called 'latexindent.pl' but not an '.exe' version. And I checked I have Perl 5v32 as well, so this is not a Perl issue.)

*latexindent* [manual](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/support/latexindent/documentation/latexindent.pdf)
reccomends the following code, saying that ''latexindent.pl ships with a script to help with this process; if you run the following script, you should be prompted to install the appropriate modules.''

```
perl latexindent-module-installer.pl
```

When I run it, I get the warning:

```
Can't open perl script "latexindent-module-installer.pl": No such file or directory
```

I tried to use ''latex-indent-module-installer.exe'' hoping that the manual does not mention Windows version, but I get the same error.

The solution in [How to use latexindent in TeXStudio on Windows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334287/how-to-use-latexindent-in-texstudio-on-windows/334511#334511) does not work as well. After I downloaded latexindent manually and put it in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexindent` I still get the error that

```
Can't locate LatexIndent/Document.pm in @INC (you may need to install the LatexIndent::Document module) (@INC contains: /c/Users/adali/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at C:\Users\adali\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts/latexindent\latexindent.pl line 27.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\adali\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts/latexindent\latexindent.pl line 27.
```

from the error message I surmise that latexindent does not look into the file that I put the executable into.

So it seems there are two problems.

1. Miktex does not install the latexindent package fully (The package was available in Miktex, and I even updated it once I encountered the problem)
2. latexindent does not search all the root texmf files one configures by Miktex.

Comment: Perhaps the solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334511/6621 might be helpful?

Comment: I tried to do it. But it didn't work. I downloaded 'latexindent' and put the file in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexindent` but I still get the error

Comment: The error message you're reporting looks like you're using the Perl version. For Windows, the only two files you need are latexindent.exe and defaultSettings.yaml, both are available from ctan. Note that Miktex might have it's own version of latexindent.exe which might be different from the ctan version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What does not work

1. Installing it through Miktex (not even several tries of deleting and re-installing)
2. Downloading the `latexindent` package and putting it in a **non-local** texmf location.
3. running the `latexindent-module-installer`.
4. trying to download perl modules through CPAN

## What works

1. Create a local texmf tree
2. Download the package from CTAN **end delete everything except latexindent.exe and defaultSettings.yaml**
3. put those two files under your local texmf tree in a folder called 'scripts'

if you still get a missing perl module error;

4. run `cpan -f -i <missingmodule>` from the **command prompt**
5. Now you can use the command `latexindent.tex myfile.tex`

## why should we resort to a manual solution

a. Miktex does not properly install `latexindent`

b. `latexindent-module-installer-pl` does not work on windows

c. cpan does download the missing modules without force installing from command prompt.

Comment: To anyone reading this : I have tried repeatedly to influence change with latexindent on Miktex, with no success. Any help appreciated (author of latexindent)

Comment: @cmhughes, any developments ?

Comment: @bambOo I'm afraid not, I have continued to fail to influence change with miktex

Comment: https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/issues?q=label%3AMikTeX+is%3Aclosed